# Civix: command not found

Tags: drupal, civix

I have downloaded, then uploaded civix.phar to my www/www directory (where Drupal is installed).

Now, if I run civix civicrm:ping (from this www/www directory), the answer is :

-bash civix: command not found

(I also tried civix.phar civicrm:ping : I get the same answer)
(I also tried from other directories : I get the same answer)

I am not a linux expert ; what am I missing ? (permission is 775)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `php civix.phar` or `./civix.phar` or first update your PATH:

`set PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/where/you/downloaded/it`

Comment: When I use php civix.phar or ./civix.phar, I get : "Failed loading /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so:  /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so: undefined symbol: zend_interrupt_function" ;

Comment: try php71 or php72 instead of php. There might be multiple versions installed.

Comment: Why should I update my PATH, since I run civix from where I downloaded it ? I did however, but no change.

Comment: Usually your extensions go in files/civicrm/ext so you usually run it from there but setting path is optional.

Comment: php71 or php 72 do not change anything ; my extensions are in www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext ; should I set the PATH there (while civix.phar is in www/www) ? My current php.ini file is as follows :zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so
post_max_size = 20M
memory_limit = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
max_execution_time = 120
expose_php = Off
session.save_path = /tmp
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
date.timezone = "Europe/Sofia"

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this on the server directly. That might be fine if it's a test site just often people do development offline on their workstation and then it's easier to control the environment. Are you open to doing this on your computer since then you could use a pre-built setup to get started such as https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit-vagrant or https://github.com/michaelmcandrew/civicrm-buildkit-docker.

Comment: If you can edit your php.ini, you can probably get things working by removing the line about ioncube.  You don't need that for CiviCRM.

Answer (score 0):

It was a php configuration issue, now solved by my hoster ; I must use php civix.phar command, and it works now.